# Como Usar Zend 2 + MapServer

Tags: php, zend

Como faço para usar as funções do `MapServer()` dentro do controller do Zend ?
Estou usando o MS4W o qual possui Apache, PHP e MapServer.

Se fosse direto, seria algo assim:

```
<?php 
$mapserver = MapServer();
$obj = $mapserver -> ms_newMapObj();
$obj -> draw();
$obj -> saveImage("mapa-exemplo" , "gif");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para todos os inetessados, consegui fazer funciona e não houve necessidades e fazer qualquer alteração.

segue trecho exemplo:

```
public function Mapserver($map , $mapPath , $img , $imgPath){
    $path = array(
        'img' => $imgPath . $img ,
        'map' => $mapPath . $map
    );

    try{
        $mapa = ms_newMapObj($path['map']);

        $mapa -> draw() 
              -> saveImage($path['img']);


    } catch (Zend_Exception $ex ) { 
        echo $ex -> getMessage();
    }
}
```